# Recursively split a string based on a delimiter for each recursion

Tags: python, string, recursion, split

I want to create a function or set of functions that recursively splits a large string/text into multiple substrings at each recursion level using RegEx. I would like the output to be a list of tuples containing the name/pattern found for each level and the lowest level text.

Example: Split entire text into chapters, split each chapter into sections, split each section into subsections. Output would be:

```
[("Chapter 1", "Section 1", "Subsection 1", "Text belonging to this particular subsection"), 
 ("Chapter 1", "Section 2", "Subsection 1", "Other text belonging to this particular subsection"), 
 ("Chapter 1", "Section 2", "Subsection 2", "Another text belonging to this particular subsection"), 
 ("Chapter 2", "Section 1", "Subsection 1", "Yet another text belonging to this particular subsection")]
```

I have this example hardcoded for 3 levels (chapter, section, subsection) for which I have a RegEx pattern delimiter at each level, see below.

However, I would like to have a function that, when I input a list of *n* RegEx delimiters, can do this splitting for *n* levels (e.g. chapter, section, subsection, subsubsection, etc.).

The problem I am having is conceptualizing how to split the different chapters/sections at each level of recursion. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I guess this could also be done with some complex RegEx pattern? I thought of doing it recursively because it followed naturally from my initial logic but I'm open to any suggestions.

---

**Current code with 3-level logic**

```
def my_split(text: str, delim: str):
    # split string
    splitted = re.split(delim, text)

    # divide into patterns split on and texts following patterns
    names = splitted[1::2]
    texts = splitted[2::2]

    return names, texts

# split into chapters
chapter_names, chapter_texts = my_split(full_text, delim_chapter)
chapters = list(zip(chapter_names, chapter_texts))

# create list to save level names and lowest level split text
subsections_list = []

# iterate through chapters and find if there are sections present
for chapter_name, chapter_text in chapters:

    # check if sections exist and create sections list
    if re.search(delim_section, chapter_text):
        section_names, section_texts = my_split(chapter_text, delim_section)
        sections = list(zip(section_names, section_texts))

    else:  # create artificial section name
        section_names, section_texts = ['Unique section'], [chapter_text]
        sections = list(zip(section_names, section_texts))

    for section_name, section_text in sections:
        # divide into subsections
        subsection_names, subsection_texts = my_split(section_text, delim_subsection)
        subsections = list(zip(subsection_names, subsection_texts))

        # get repeated chapter and section names to put in tuples with subsections and text
        chapter_names = [chapter_name] * len(subsections)
        section_names = [section_name] * len(subsections)

        # create list of tuples containing all subsections names and text
        chapter_section_subsection_text = list(
            zip(chapter_names, section_names, subsection_names, subsection_texts))

        # save to list
        subsections_list.append(chapter_section_subsection_text)

subsections_flat_list = [item for sublist in subsections_list for item in sublist]
```

Comment: The function should take a list of delimiters. It splits the text using the first delimiter, then loops over the results and calls itself recursively on that result and `delims[1:]`. It stops when the delimiter list is empty.

Comment: Thanks, @Barmar. I will try to implement this.